# Google Sheets Query with Indirect Address

Tags: google-sheets

I am running into issues with this query and am unsure of what is going wrong.

I tried various formatting setups but nothing seems to work.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15GkrohT_eCuJOtUYvoLaCWMeGJ5rauF0Duj-fBxPNBg/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to have imported data be queried and organized to then be pulled into a weekly format on 'TestingMain'.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'ifna(QUERY(Testing2!$A:$F,"select E where A='"&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row(), 1))&"' AND B= date '" &TEXT(DATEVALUE(E2),"yyyy-mm-dd")& "' ",0), 0)'

Comment: Could you include whats the current behavior and what is the expected behavior that you want?

Comment: @GabrielCarballo I am trying to pull the Order Net amount from Testing2 into TestingMain in the correct row and column. Currently it only pulls 0 instead of the correct number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not solved the problem per se, but I found a work around. The problem lay in the first leg of the WHERE clause so instead of having the indirect address formula, I just had a different string for each row.

`ifna(QUERY(Testing2!$A:$F,"select E where A='one' AND B= date '" &TEXT(DATEVALUE(E2),"yyyy-mm-dd")& "' ",0), 0)`